# How to change error behavior of Flex lexer?

Tags: yacc, flex-lexer, lexer, bisonc++

I have built a lexer with Flex. There is one major problem though: Flex by default generates this error method:

```
void yyFlexLexer::LexerError( yyconst char msg[] )
{
    std::cerr << msg << std::endl;
    exit( YY_EXIT_FAILURE );
}
```

That means that on every syntax error my application just quits. Of course that's not what I want, since I need to call the lexer over and over even with faulty inputs.

Is there a way to change Flex's behavior on this?

Answer (score 1):

Solved it! I just added a simple "#define YY_FATAL_ERROR" to the top of my .l file.
This will make sure that Flex won't call the LexerError-method and thus the application does not exit.